# Find the volume of a pyramid

Tags: geometry, volume

Consider the triangle drawn on a sheet of paper, along with the coordinate axes, whose vertices are the points $(0,0)$, $(34,0)$ and $(16,24)$.
The vertices of your middle triangle are the midpoints of their sides. A triangular pyramid isformed by folding the triangle along the sides of its middle triangle. Determine the volume of this pyramid.(S:$408$)

[image]

I calculated the area of ​​the base but how to find the height of the pyramid?

$$S_{base}=\dfrac{DE\cdot h}{2}=\dfrac{12\cdot 17}{12}=102.$$

Answer (score 5):

We claim that the upper vertex of the pyramid is $V=(16,12,12)$ (and the face $CDE$ is orthogonal to the base $DEF$).
It suffices to verify that the distance between $V$ and the vertices of the base, i. e. $D=(8,12,0)$, $E=(25,12,0)$ and $F=(17,0,0)$:
$$\begin{align}
|VD|^2&=8^2+0^2+12^2=8^2+12^2=|AD|^2=|CD|^2\\
|VE|^2&=9^2+0^2+12^2=9^2+12^2=|CE|^2=|BE|^2\\
|VF|^2&=1+12^2+12^2=289=17^2=|BF|^2=|AF|^2.
\end{align}$$
It follows that $h=12$ and
$$V=\frac{S_{base}\cdot h}{3}=\frac{102\cdot 12}{3}=408.$$

More generally we may use use the [Cayley-Menger Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%E2%80%93Menger_determinant) with $n=3$:
$$\begin{align}
V^2&=\frac{1}{(3!)^2\cdot 2^3}\det\begin{bmatrix}0 & d_{01}^2 & d_{02}^2 & d_{03}^2 & 1\\ d_{01}^2 & 0 & d_{12}^2 & d_{13}^2 & 1\\
d_{02}^2 & d_{12}^2 & 0 & d_{23}^2 & 1\\
d_{03}^2 & d_{13}^2 & d_{23}^2 & 0 & 1\\
1 & 1& 1& 1 &0
\end{bmatrix}\\
&=\frac{1}{288}\det\begin{bmatrix}0 & 9^2+12^2 & 17^2 & 8^2+12^2 & 1\\ 9^2+12^2 & 0 & 8^2+12^2 & 17^2 & 1\\
17^2 & 8^2+12^2  & 0 & 9^2+12^2 & 1\\
8^2+12^2 & 17^2 & 9^2+12^2 & 0 & 1\\
1 & 1& 1& 1 &0
\end{bmatrix}=408^2
\end{align}$$
where $d_{i j}$ is the Euclidean distances between vertices $V_i$ and $V_{j}$.

Comment: Thanks for help, Could you explain better, I'm not able to visualize this orthogonality?

Comment: @petaarantes Please see my edit

Comment: I see, but My main question is how do I guarantee that when folding the triangles on the edges of the base they will meet at the vertex you mentioned (16,12,12)

Comment: Above the base there is exactly one point $V$ which has those distances from $D, E,F$ (it is the intersection point between 3 spheres).

Answer (score 1):

If we form the pyramid by doubling the segments that are the sides of the middle triangle, the necessary and sufficient condition for a pyramid to be formed is that the points $A,B,C$ are found in the rotation by the axes $DF,EF,ED$, but such rotation is in the plane perpendicular to the axis of rotation. In short, the projection of the vertex of the pyramid will be the orthocenter of $ABC$. The height will be $VC$

[image]

$S_{(base)}=\dfrac{DE.h}{2}=\dfrac{17.12}{2}=102\\
\therefore V = \dfrac{102.12}{3}= \boxed{408}$

(S:ancape)